# how to create a button on a Sharepoint 2013 web page which gives the count of items from a specific view in a list

Tags: sharepoint-2013, listviewitem

I am trying to figure out if I can create an Info "button" in a Sharepoint web page that will give me a count of the number of items in a specific view of a list.  That view has calculated fields.

The list is an approvals list.  It only displays items that the person logged on has to approve.  Once they approve, the item is removed from the list view.  I want to have a way to show that person how many approvals are left for each of the views I have created.  I cannot changed the views.

I am not a developer but do understand how to add HTML code to a webpage.  We are not allowed to run jQuery.

Thanks!

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a site "Do the job for me", show what you try; otherwise I think is better to pay someone to do the job. Anyway search google for **Develop Sharepoint 2013**

Comment: I thought this was a forum where I could get help. I just want to know if it's even possible using HTML. I believe my first sentence says that. I gave background as info only...not so someone can do the work for me. You obviously don't believe in sharing info with beginners. Thanks for nothing, my mistake.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask